# cassandra composite index and compact storages

Tags: cassandra, composite-index

I am new in cassandra, have not run it yet, but my business logic requires to create such table.

```
CREATE TABLE Index( 
  user_id uuid, 
  keyword text, 
  score text, 
  fID int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, keyword, score); ) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC) and COMPACT STORAGE;
```

Is it possible or not? I have only one column(fID) which is not part of my composite index, so i hope I will be able to apply compact_storage setting. Pay attention thet I ordered by third column of my composite index, not second. I need to compact the storage as well, so the keywords will not be repeated for each fID.

Answer (score 0):

A few things initially about your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

1. It will error on the semicolon (`;`) after your PRIMARY KEY definition.
2. You will need to pick a new name, as `Index` is a [reserved word](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/keywords_r.html).

> Pay attention thet I ordered by third column of my composite index, not second.

3. You cannot skip a [clustering key](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html) when you specify `CLUSTERING ORDER`.

However, I do see an option here.  Depending on your query requirements, you could simply re-order `keyword` and `score` in your PRIMARY KEY definition, and then it would work:

```
CREATE TABLE giveMeABetterName(
  user_id uuid, 
  keyword text, 
  score text, 
  fID int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, score, keyword)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC) and COMPACT STORAGE;
```

That way, you could query by `user_id` and your rows (keywords?) for that user would be ordered by `score`:

```
SELECT * FROM giveMeABetterName WHERE `user_id`=1b325b66-8ae5-4a2e-a33d-ee9b5ad464b4;
```

If that won't work for your business logic, then you might have to retouch your data model.  But it is not possible to skip a clustering key when specifying `CLUSTERING ORDER`.

**Edit**

> But re-ordering of columns does not work for me. Can I do something like this `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (keyword asc, score desc)`

Let's look at some options here.  I created a table with your original PRIMARY KEY, but with this CLUSTERING ORDER.  That will technically work, but look at how it treats my sample data (video game keywords):

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM givemeabettername WHERE user_id=dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f;
 user_id                              | keyword          | score | fid
--------------------------------------+------------------+-------+-----
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f | Assassin's creed |    87 |   0
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |    Battlefield 4 |     9 |   0
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |      Uncharted 2 |    91 |   0

(3 rows)
```

On the other hand, if I alter the PRIMARY KEY to cluster on `score` first (and adjust CLUSTERING ORDER accordingly), the same query returns this:

```
 user_id                              | score | keyword          | fid
--------------------------------------+-------+------------------+-----
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |    91 |      Uncharted 2 |   0
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |    87 | Assassin's creed |   0
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |     9 |    Battlefield 4 |   0
```

Note that  you'll want to change the data type of `score` from TEXT to a numeric (int/bigint) to avoid ASCII-betical sorting, like this:

```
 user_id                              | score | keyword          | fid
--------------------------------------+-------+------------------+-----
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |    91 |      Uncharted 2 |   0
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |     9 |    Battlefield 4 |   0
 dbeddd12-40c9-4f84-8c41-162dfb93a69f |    87 | Assassin's creed |   0
```

Something that might help you, is to read through this DataStax doc on [Compound Keys and Clustering](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html).

Comment: Thanks @BryceAtNetwork23 for detailed answer. But re-ordering of columns does not work for me. Can I do something like this 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (keyword asc, score desc) and COMPACT STORAGE???

Comment: @user3201666 Edit made.  I added some examples, as well as a link to a DataStax doc covering a similar use case.

Comment: Thanks @BryceAtNetwork23. I got it. My business logic is the following

Comment: Thanks @BryceAtNetwork23. I got it. My business logic is the following. Each keyword can be contained in many many files. And in each file the keyword may have different score exposing the file relevance to the keyword. So i need the following nested  map Map<User_id, Map<Keyword, Map<Score, LIST_OF(fids)>>>> and i want to query all keyword related files having the highest score... Just can not build the right Cassandra table. Also the storage efficiency is important that is why I thought to use COMPACT_STORAGE...